# indexing a numpy array containing functions

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Numpy array, "nFuncs" containing function objects as blow:

```
array([ [<bound method ncNN.sigmoid of <__main__.ncNN object at 0x11c01f510>>, 
         <bound method ncNN.sigmoid of <__main__.ncNN object at 0x11c01f510>>, 
         <bound method ncNN.sigmoid of <__main__.ncNN object at 0x11c01f510>>],
        [<bound method ncNN.sigmoid of <__main__.ncNN object at 0x11c01f510>>,
         <bound method ncNN.sigmoid of <__main__.ncNN object at 0x11c01f510>>]], dtype=object)
```

What's the legitimate way to index this array?
when I tried nFuncs[1,1], I have IndexError: too many indices for array. However, nFuncs[1][1] works. Can you explain why I cannot use nFuncs[1,1]?

Comment: It could be stored as list of list.
Have you tried `type(nFuncs[1])`?

Comment: What's the `shape`?

Comment: @hpaulj it is (2,)

Comment: @DeanLa yes, it is a list.

Comment: So it is 1d, and can only be indexed with `[1]`.

Comment: @hpaulj Can you please explain why it is regarded as 1d, even thought it has nested components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a nested list:

```
In [8]: alist=[[1,2,3],[4,5]]
In [9]: len(alist)
Out[9]: 2
```

It's a list of 2 items; the items happen to be lists.  In some sort meta view it is 2d, but nothing about the list itself is 2d.

Make an array from it:

```
In [10]: arr = np.array(alist)
In [11]: arr.shape
Out[11]: (2,)
In [12]: arr.dtype
Out[12]: dtype('O')
In [13]: arr
Out[13]: array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]], dtype=object)
In [14]: arr[0]
Out[14]: [1, 2, 3]
In [15]: type(arr[0])
Out[15]: list
```

It too has 2 elements, in fact the same 2 sublists as `alist` (same id)

```
In [16]: id(alist[0])
Out[16]: 2992863468
In [17]: id(arr[0])
Out[17]: 2992863468
```

If I change an element of one of those sublists, the change appears in the other structure

```
In [18]: arr[0][1]=3
In [19]: arr
Out[19]: array([[1, 3, 3], [4, 5]], dtype=object)
In [20]: alist
Out[20]: [[1, 3, 3], [4, 5]]
```

For most purposes an object array like this is just like a list.  You can reshape it, eg. `arr.reshape(2,1)', but you can't append to it.  And to perform most actions you (or numpy) has to iterate through the elements just as if it were a list.

Contrast that with a 2d array of integers

```
In [21]: A=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
In [22]: A
Out[22]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
In [23]: A.shape
Out[23]: (2, 3)
In [24]: A.dtype
Out[24]: dtype('int32')
```

May be it will to visualize the `object` barrier if I change the elements of `arr` into arrays:

```
In [26]: arr[0]=np.array(arr[0])
In [27]: arr[1]=np.array(arr[1])
In [28]: arr
Out[28]: array([array([1, 3, 3]), array([4, 5])], dtype=object)
```

It is now an array of arrays; but that still not the same as a 2d array.

Comment: I really appreciate your kind explanation. Now I think I started to understand the difference between object array and some other types(?) of array. A few more questions. When does an array is initiated as an object array and fixed type array? For example, `A = np.array([['1','1'],['sd','a']])` makes "'|S2'" type(?) 2D array, not an object array. Then, can I think that, if I create an array with sub elements with the same lengths, it will always make a fixed type multi-dimensional array? Also, can you please explain the rationale behind A[x,x] indexing in higher dimension arrays?

Comment: `np.array` tries to create as high a dimension array as it can - working all the way down through equal length nested arrays.  Limiting that depth requires some trickery.  It's been the subject of a number of SO questions.

Comment: Thanks very much. I will look into more documentations

Answer (score 1):

The array has shape (2,): It is 1-dimensional. This is because the first and the second sub-lists in the constructor have different lengths. So this is interpreted as a 1-d array of 2 lists. To get an array of functions insert a function into the second list (or remove one from the first).

Comment: Thanks for your input. Then, if I just want to use the array as above, is it the only way to index like name[I][j]?

Comment: In any case you have to first index into the array and then into the resulting list. There are in principle more complicated ways to index into the array, but I think that will not make sense or help in your case.

Comment: Then, Numpy arrays like a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]) are an exception, given that I can access an element using a[1, 2]?

Comment: More the rule than the exception :) To access an element like that you need a 2D array, which can't be constructed from 2 lists of differing lengths, so numpy doesn't and gives you an array of lists instead.